# Does using inline keyword in methods definition may cause ptoblems?

Tags: c++, c

I used inline in every method in my program (implementation of algorithm), does it can make problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on what your code looks like.

But *not understanding what your code means*? That is **definitely** going to cause you problems.

Why don't you try to learn what `inline` actually *does*, rather than simply whether or not it's going to cause any problems?

The primary effect of the `inline` keyword in C++ is to make the compiler suppress the ODR (One Definition Rule). So a non-`inline` function must be defined in exactly *one* translation unit.

An `inline` function must be defined in every translation where it's used.

So depending on how and where your function is defined, `inline` may or may not be *correct*. I suggest you use it where its use is correct.

Answer (score -1):

It may make your compiled output larger and run more slowly, assuming the compiler isn't smart enough to ignore it. Generally, you should only use optimizations keywords like 'register' or 'inline' if you have a specific purpose in mind -- a case where you know something useful that the compiler does not know.

On modern CPUs, inlining is frequently a pessimization rather than an optimization. This is because each copy of the function must be fetched from memory, have its instructions decoded, and uses up its own space in the various caches -- particularly the branch prediction cache.

Comment: -1, inline functions make branch prediction and caching more efficient because the function is located right at the place it's called from, not elsewhere in the code section. jumping places is what produces cache misses.

Comment: @pezcode: Huh? How would a jump produce a cache miss? Jumps are 100% predictable. And if the function was recently called from elsewhere, it will be hot in the caches.